# Status Start and end dates with multiple status changes for same user/customer - SQL

Tags: sql

I have a customer who has changed on status multiple times , I need to fetch the status lifecycle (start and end date within particular status ) and if the status is back again , it would show the latest dates when the status changed ( for ex: Active should come as 2 rows below one with old dates and one with recent dates) 
Please help on this HiveQL / SQL

```
Customer  Status    date
abc active           5/1
abc active           5/2
abc active           5/3
abc temp deactivate  5/4
abc temp deactivate  5/5
abc deactivate   5/6
abc active           5/7
abc active           5/8
abc active           5/9
abc active           5/10
```

Output :

```
customer status       start date    end date
abc  active       5/1           5/3
abc  temp deactivate  5/4           5/5
abc  deactivate   5/6           5/6
abc  active           5/7           5/10
```

Comment: It' s really complex to implement this in a SQL way, but not impossible, the window function maybe finish it. let me think.

Comment: I have give my answer, just check it :D

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have solved this problem now, just use the window function `row_number` twice, the SQL as below:

```
select
    customer,
    status,
    min(date) as start_date,
    max(date) as end_date
from
    (
    select
        date,
        customer,
        status,
        row_number() over (order by date) as seq_num,
        row_number() over (partition by customer,status order by date) as seqnum_s
    from
        customer_table
    ) as tmp
group by
    customer,
    status,
    seq_num-seqnum_s
order by
    start_date;
 customer |     status      | start_date |  end_date  
----------+-----------------+------------+------------
 abc      | active          | 2019-05-01 | 2019-05-03
 abc      | temp deactivate | 2019-05-04 | 2019-05-05
 abc      | deactivate      | 2019-05-06 | 2019-05-06
 abc      | active          | 2019-05-07 | 2019-05-10
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it's close. Hopefully someone can build on this to complete the answer.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    customer VARCHAR(3),
    status VARCHAR(15),
    date DATE
    );

INSERT 
    INTO @t (customer, [status], [date]) 
    VALUES
        ('abc','active','5/1/2019'),
        ('abc','active','5/2/2019'),
        ('abc','active','5/3/2019'),
        ('abc','temp deactivate','5/4/2019'),
        ('abc','temp deactivate','5/5/2019'),
        ('abc','deactivate','5/6/2019'),
        ('abc','active','5/7/2019'),
        ('abc','active','5/8/2019'),
        ('abc','active','5/9/2019'),
        ('abc','active','5/10/2019');


;WITH 
    cte1 AS (
        SELECT 
            t.[customer],
            t.[status],
            LAG(t.[status], 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY t.[date]) AS [prev_status],
            LEAD(t.[status], 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY t.[date]) AS [next_status],
            t.[date]
        FROM @t AS t)
    ,cte2 AS (
        SELECT 
            cte1.[customer],
            cte1.[status],
            CASE WHEN cte1.[prev_status] = cte1.[status] THEN NULL ELSE cte1.[date] END AS [min],
            CASE WHEN cte1.[next_status] = cte1.[status] THEN NULL ELSE cte1.[date] END AS [max],
            cte1.[date]
        FROM cte1)
SELECT
    cte2.[customer],
    cte2.[status], 
    cte2.[min] AS [start_date], 
    cte2.[max] AS [end_date]
FROM cte2 ;
```

this returns the following non-collapsed result:

[image]