# Entity Framework query - select only record until timestamp from another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables.

The 1st one is `History` table - data received by different devices.

```
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| DeviceId | Temperature | TimeStamp          |
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1        | 31          | 15.08.2020 1:42:00 |
| 2        | 40          | 15.08.2020 1:43:00 |
| 1        | 32          | 15.08.2020 1:44:00 |
| 1        | 34          | 15.08.2020 1:45:00 |
| 1        | 20          | 15.08.2020 1:46:00 |
| 2        | 45          | 15.08.2020 1:47:00 |
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
```

The 2nd one is `DeviceStatusHistory` table

```
+----------+---------+--------------------+
| DeviceId | Status  | TimeStamp          |
+----------+---------+--------------------+
| 1        | 1(OK)   | 15.08.2020 1:42:00 |
| 2        | 1(OK)   | 15.08.2020 1:43:00 |
| 1        | 1(OK)   | 15.08.2020 1:44:00 |
| 1        | 0(FAIL) | 15.08.2020 1:44:30 |
| 1        | 0(FAIL) | 15.08.2020 1:46:00 |
| 2        | 0(FAIL) | 15.08.2020 1:46:10 |
+----------+---------+--------------------+
```

Since the device1 starts failing from 15.08.2020 1:44:30, I don't want its record that goes after that timestamp.

The same for the device2.

So as a final result I want to have only data of all devices until they get first FAIL status:

```
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| DeviceId | Temperature | TimeStamp          |
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1        | 31          | 15.08.2020 1:42:00 |
| 2        | 40          | 15.08.2020 1:43:00 |
| 1        | 32          | 15.08.2020 1:44:00 |
+----------+-------------+--------------------+
```

I tried something like this

```cs
var query = _context
            .History
            .Include(h => h.Device)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(h => h.DeviceTimeStamp <= h.Device.DeviceStatusHistory.FirstOrDefault(st => st.Status == 0).TimeStamp);
```

The problems is if a device never fails, I don't get its history at all.

Comment: what you get with the current query?

Comment: @AndySong I get the right result only if device has FAIL status somewhere in DeviceStatusHistory table, otherwise I get empty result

Comment: I don't think it is achievable by a single linq query. As the devices come back online you would want to retrieve  those values too. So you need a query like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56521824/12354911) answer to group status changes to get the start and end dates and then make a second query joining to that query to not to retrieve the values between the start and end dates which has fail status.

Comment: @Eldar Device never come back to OK state after FAIL, so all that I need is to get history until devices fails.

Comment: Ah then @IvanStoev's answer should work in theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need "not exists" condition, i.e. get all `History` records for which does not exist `DeviceStatusHistory` record with the same `DeviceId`, `Status == 0` and greater `Timestamp`.

Which with navigation properties in LINQ is expressed with `!Any(...)` condition rather than `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
.Where(h => !h.Device.DeviceStatusHistory.Any(st =>
    st.Status == 0 && st.TimeStamp > h.DeviceTimeStamp));
```

Comment: the only thing is that it should be _st.TimeStamp <= h.DeviceTimeStamp_

Answer (score 1):

I have some untested code, can you try it. I think the logic should work for you.

```cs
var query = _context
            .History
            .Include(h => h.Device)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(
h => h.DeviceTimeStamp <= h.Device.DeviceStatusHistory.FirstOrDefault(st => st.Status == 0)?.TimeStamp ?? DateTime.MaxValue);
```

Comment: An expression tree may not contain conditional access operator

Answer (score 1):

Below SQL query works for your needs

```
select * from History h 
where h.TimeStamp < coalesce(
  (
  select min(TimeStamp) from DeviceStatusHistory where Status = 0 and DeviceId = h.DeviceId
) ,Curdate()
)
```

If we try to translate it to linq it will be like this :

```
.Where(h => h.DeviceTimeStamp < (h.Device.DeviceStatusHistory
                                 .Where(st => st.Status == 0) 
                                 .Min(st=> st.TimeStamp) ?? DateTime.Now))
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c22dfe/9)